# Change mac address on a wireshark packet

Tags: networking

I have captured a sip packet using wireshark. I am trying to replay that packet on a different network. I need to change the source/destination ip as well as source/destination mac address in this packet. How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried a hex editor yet?

Comment: Never mind. I used tcprewrite --enet-dmac=  --enet-smac --infile= --outfile=   to do what i need.